# delete subdirectories only at maxdepth 2 and above

Tags: linux, find

I have directory with 6 subdirectories but I wish to delete subdirectories from only 3 of them, hence I used a for loop to 'cd' inside these 3 directories, but I want to delete the subdirectories at depth 2 (maxdepth, mindepth as 2) inside the 3 subdirectories. I was using a find command at base(base is one of the 3 sub-directories) but it will find the directories from depth 1 (which is expected)

my file structure is
`/a/b/c/d/e` (a is one of the 3 directories I'm iterating over)

a part of he code is below where I would need help/guidance -
`find /a -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30`

this will output - `./b/c`

So I do **not** wish to delete the directory `/b` and delete only directory `c` and below/inside depths

Is there a way to do this or I will HAVE to cd to the `b` directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
find /a /b /c -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?